# Intent does not have extra after onBackPressed

Tags: java, android, android-intent

**Update: When the Android back button is pressed (the default on at the bottom of the screen), everything works perfectly, this only seems to be an issue with the menu back button...**

I am trying to pass the following intents from my [CustomCalendarView](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gHuSq.png) to `WorkoutButtonsActivity`:

`date                          //the date clicked on in the calendar`

`datesFormattedList            //all 42 visible dates on the calendar`

My current method of passing intents works perfectly, however when I move from `WorkoutButtonsActivity` to a third activity and then press back in the menu, while the date intent is still kept, I lose the 'datesFormattedList`.

`if (intent.hasExtra(EXTRA_VISIBLE_DATES))` is false.

I have declared all 3 activities launchModes in the manifest as singleTop, however this does not seem to help.

How could I ensure `datesFormattedList` is kept, even after back button is pressed?

**CalendarView** (Activity 1)

```
public class CustomCalendarView extends LinearLayout {

//initialisation removed for readability


    public CustomCalendarView(final Context context, @Nullable AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
        this.context = context;
        InitializeLayout();
        SetUpCalendar();

        gridView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(context);
                builder.setCancelable(true);

                final String date = eventDateFormat.format(dates.get(position));
                final ArrayList<String> arrayListDateFormattedList = (ArrayList<String>)datesFormattedList;

                Intent i = new Intent(getContext(), WorkoutButtonsActivity.class);
                i.putExtra(WorkoutButtonsActivity.EXTRA_DATE, date);
                i.putExtra(WorkoutButtonsActivity.EXTRA_VISIBLE_DATES, arrayListDateFormattedList);

                getContext().startActivity(i);
            }
        });
    }

    public CustomCalendarView(Context context, @Nullable AttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr);
    }

    private void InitializeLayout() {
        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.calendar_layout, this);
        NextButton = view.findViewById(R.id.nextBtn);
        PreviousButton = view.findViewById(R.id.previousBtn);
        CurrentDate = view.findViewById(R.id.current_Date);
        gridView = view.findViewById(R.id.gridview);
    }

    void SetUpCalendar() {

        datesFormattedList.clear();

        String currentDate = dateFormat.format(calendar.getTime());
        CurrentDate.setText(currentDate);
        dates.clear();
        Calendar monthCalendar = (Calendar) calendar.clone();
        monthCalendar.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, 1);
        int FirstDayofMonth = monthCalendar.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK) - 2;
        monthCalendar.add(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, -FirstDayofMonth);

        while (dates.size() < MAX_CALENDAR_DAYS) {
            dates.add(monthCalendar.getTime());
            monthCalendar.add(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, 1);
        }
        /*THIS CONVERTS THE LIST OF ALL VISIBLE DATES TO A STRING */
        for (int i = 0; i< MAX_CALENDAR_DAYS; i++) {
            final String dateFormatted = eventDateFormat.format(dates.get(i));
            datesFormattedList.add(dateFormatted);
        }
        ChangeMonth();
    }

    public void ChangeMonth() {

        logEntriesViewModel = ViewModelProviders.of((FragmentActivity) context).get(LogEntriesViewModel.class);
        logEntriesViewModel.setFilter(datesFormattedList);
        logEntriesViewModel.getDatesFilteredByMonth().observe((FragmentActivity) context, logDates -> setData(logDates));
    }
    private void setData(List<String> logDates) {

        logDatesList.clear();
        logDatesList.addAll(logDates);
        Set<String> setWithUniqueValues = new HashSet<>(logDatesList);
        uniqueDatesWithLogEntries = new ArrayList<>(setWithUniqueValues);

        myGridAdapter = new MyGridAdapter(context, dates, calendar,uniqueDatesWithLogEntries);
        gridView.setAdapter(myGridAdapter);
    }
}
```

**WorkoutButtonsActivity** (Activity 2 - Relevant code)

```
 @Override
            protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
                super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
                setContentView(R.layout.workout_list);

                getSupportActionBar().setHomeAsUpIndicator(R.drawable.ic_back);

                Intent intent = getIntent();

//THIS RETURNS TRUE AFTER BACK BUTTON PRESSED
                if (intent.hasExtra(EXTRA_DATE)) {
                    SELECTED_DATE = intent.getStringExtra(EXTRA_DATE);
                }

                setTitle(SELECTED_DATE);


// THIS RETURNS FALSE AFTER BACK BUTTON PRESSED
                if (intent.hasExtra(EXTRA_VISIBLE_DATES)) {

            EXTRA_VISIBLE_DATESS = intent.getStringArrayListExtra(EXTRA_VISIBLE_DATES);

            if (SELECTED_DATE != null && !SELECTED_DATE.isEmpty()) {
                index_number = EXTRA_VISIBLE_DATESS.indexOf(SELECTED_DATE) + 1;
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

You could hold the data outside of your activity. So you don't have to bother with lifecycle issues.

Try something simple like this:

```
public class DateKeeper{
    static ArrayList<String> calendarDates = new ArrayList<>();
    
    static void addToDates(String _date){
        calendarDates.add(_date);
    }
    
    static ArrayList<String> getDates(){
        return calendarDates;
    }
}
```

It should work, but surely there is a more elegant solution.

Answer (score 0):

Try with this:

```
@Override
   public void onBackPressed() {
       //intent here, and extra data....etc....
     }
```

And pass data and open intent in this...